# Please undelete this question

Tags: support

I deleted this question because I thought its irrelevant: [Why did Standard Model never sense a requirement to include gravitational quantum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31434/why-did-standard-model-never-sense-a-requirement-to-include-gravitational-quantu)

But, [someone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1492/anna-v) from community told me that its reasonable. So, I want to undelete it. Unfortunately, I am unable to see it as I don't have 10k reputation.. so no luck in getting to undelete link.

Can you please undelete it if you have its permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, I undeleted it. .................